# How to specify function signature for a method using custom types in numba

Tags: python, numpy, numba

I use the `numba.jitclass` decorator to mark my class for optimization.

I don't know how to specify the signature of the `run` method that I want to optimize. The method takes an array of `ConvertedDocument` objects as an argument. It seems that numba is not able to figure out the array type on its own as the following error occurs when I try to invoke the run method in a nopython mode:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "numba_test.py", line 53, in <module>
    print run(a)
  File "/home/clasocki/anaconda2/envs/my_numba_env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numba/dispatcher.py", line 310, in _compile_for_args
    raise e
numba.errors.TypingError: Caused By:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/clasocki/anaconda2/envs/my_numba_env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numba/compiler.py", line 230, in run
    stage()
  File "/home/clasocki/anaconda2/envs/my_numba_env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numba/compiler.py", line 444, in stage_nopython_frontend
    self.locals)
  File "/home/clasocki/anaconda2/envs/my_numba_env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numba/compiler.py", line 800, in type_inference_stage
    infer.propagate()
  File "/home/clasocki/anaconda2/envs/my_numba_env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numba/typeinfer.py", line 767, in propagate
    raise errors[0]
TypingError: Internal error at <numba.typeinfer.ExhaustIterConstraint object at 0x788cc9572d50>:
--%<-----------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/clasocki/anaconda2/envs/my_numba_env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numba/typeinfer.py", line 128, in propagate
    constraint(typeinfer)
  File "/home/clasocki/anaconda2/envs/my_numba_env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numba/typeinfer.py", line 264, in __call__
    raise TypingError("failed to unpack {}".format(tp), loc=self.loc)
  File "/home/clasocki/anaconda2/envs/my_numba_env/lib/python2.7/contextlib.py", line 35, in __exit__
    self.gen.throw(type, value, traceback)
  File "/home/clasocki/anaconda2/envs/my_numba_env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numba/errors.py", line 249, in new_error_context
    six.reraise(type(newerr), newerr, sys.exc_info()[2])
  File "/home/clasocki/anaconda2/envs/my_numba_env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numba/errors.py", line 243, in new_error_context
    yield
  File "/home/clasocki/anaconda2/envs/my_numba_env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numba/typeinfer.py", line 264, in __call__
    raise TypingError("failed to unpack {}".format(tp), loc=self.loc)
InternalError: local variable 'tp' referenced before assignment
[1] During: typing of exhaust iter at numba_test.py (40)
--%<-----------------------------------------------------------------

File "numba_test.py", line 40

Failed at nopython (nopython frontend)
Internal error at <numba.typeinfer.ExhaustIterConstraint object at 0x788cc9572d50>:
--%<-----------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/clasocki/anaconda2/envs/my_numba_env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numba/typeinfer.py", line 128, in propagate
    constraint(typeinfer)
  File "/home/clasocki/anaconda2/envs/my_numba_env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numba/typeinfer.py", line 264, in __call__
    raise TypingError("failed to unpack {}".format(tp), loc=self.loc)
  File "/home/clasocki/anaconda2/envs/my_numba_env/lib/python2.7/contextlib.py", line 35, in __exit__
    self.gen.throw(type, value, traceback)
  File "/home/clasocki/anaconda2/envs/my_numba_env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numba/errors.py", line 249, in new_error_context
    six.reraise(type(newerr), newerr, sys.exc_info()[2])
  File "/home/clasocki/anaconda2/envs/my_numba_env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numba/errors.py", line 243, in new_error_context
    yield
  File "/home/clasocki/anaconda2/envs/my_numba_env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numba/typeinfer.py", line 264, in __call__
    raise TypingError("failed to unpack {}".format(tp), loc=self.loc)
InternalError: local variable 'tp' referenced before assignment
[1] During: typing of exhaust iter at numba_test.py (40)
--%<-----------------------------------------------------------------

File "numba_test.py", line 40

This error may have been caused by the following argument(s):
- argument 0: Unsupported array dtype: object
```

Here's how I specify the numba decorators:

```
spec = [
    ('profile', numba.typeof(numpy.asarray([1.0, 2.0]))),
    ('word_weights', numba.typeof(numpy.asarray([(1.0,2.0)])))
]

@numba.jitclass(spec)
class ConvertedDocument(object):
    def __init__(self, profile, word_weights):
        self.profile = profile
        self.word_weights = word_weights

@numba.jit(nopython=True,cache=True)
def run(docs):
    s = 0
    for doc in docs: #array of documents
        for w_id, weight in doc.word_weights: #accessing document's property
            s += weight

    return s
```

And this is the way the `run` method is called:

```
x = numpy.asarray([1.0, 2.0])
y = numpy.asarray([(1.0,2.0), (3.0,4.0)])
a = numpy.asarray([ConvertedDocument(x,y)])
print run(a)
```

If the `a` numpy array is replaced with a Python list, the exception is as follows:

```
Failed at nopython (nopython mode backend)
reflected list(instance.jitclass.ConvertedDocument#3bffb70<profile:array(float64, 1d, C),word_weights:array(float64, 2d, C)>): unsupported nested memory-managed object
```

Does anyone know how to specify a method signature when custom types are used or whether the iteration over an array of objects is supported or not?

Answer (score 0):

The problem appears to be that you can't call `np.nditer` on a `jitclass` object, which makes sense since a `jitclass` isn't iterable. It stores it's data as a struct of arrays (and other data types) rather than an array of structs. You are attempting to use it as the latter. It would be ambiguous as to how you'd iterate over the jitclass object if in addition to your two array attributes you also had a bunch of scalar data attributes or arrays of differing sizes.

The error message is admittedly unclear. My advice would to iterate over the index of `word_weights` you need directly.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. The thing is that `docs` is an array of documents - not a single `jitclass` object so I'm trying to iterate over an iterable array of documents. I updated my example by removing the `np.nditer` which probably wasn't necessary at all and was causing the previous error. Now the error is different and suggests that this kind of iteration might not be supported at the moment, but I'm not sure.